# O meu valor é substituído no LocalStorage

Tags: angular, localstorage

Estou tentando adicionar dados no LocalStorage através de um form. Porem, ele sempre substitui o valor e não aparece a chave que eu havia determinado (fica como 1).

Nesse trecho de código é quando ele pega o objeto user (é um input) e envia para o LocalStorage apenas o "user.name". Ele envia o valor.

```
register(user: User) {
    this.user = new User;
    window.localStorage.setItem('user', user.name);
}
```

Resultado no LocalStorage :

[image: LocalStorage]

Dá para observar que a chave (key) não é a que eu setei (user). E consequentemente, quando faço outras inserções, com outras chaves, ele substitui o valor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Era problema do navegador (opera).
Se alguém futuramente estar com o mesmo problema que eu, teste sua aplicação em outro navegador.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode armazenar um objeto json no localstorage. Se você estiver usando jquery, pode aplicar o JSON.stringfy(obj) e armazenar o objeto textualmente.

```js
var objs = {
  list: []
};

$(document).ready(function () {

  objs.list.push({nome: '', id: 1});
  
  //PARA ADICIONAR
  localStorage.setItem('nome', JSON.stringify(objs));

  //PARA PEGAR
  objs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('nome'));
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```